# Data table Sort order not working my application

Tags: javascript, jquery

Datatable sort order not working my application anybody help me.

```
$('#jTable').dataTable( 
{
"bSort" : false
} );
```

Comment: you set `"bSort" : false` - so it's disabled for that column - so no sort - what's the problem? Btw. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$('#jTable').dataTable( { "bSort" : true } );
```

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features

If you want by default order by some specific columns you can add this config:

```
$('#jTable').dataTable( { "bSort" : true,
                          "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]] } );
```

In this case would order DESC in the first column.

More info:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: @RajeshKannan check my response now i added more data. But everything was in the dataTables documentation...

Comment: @RajeshKannan could you validate the response as OK, so more people could use it on future? Thanks!

Comment: I need one more help for you

Comment: How to validate checked box like chk[] this type

Comment: @RajeshKannan but that question is not related with datatables right? what do you mean exactly? check if a checkbox is selected??

Comment: @RajeshKannan could you also validate the response for the community? Thanks

Comment: $('#jTable').dataTable( { "bSort" : true,
                          "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]] } );
Sort order not working properly

Comment: @RajeshKannan check the code i updated in the response with aaSorting